# Best practice on use of C++ lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm studying the C++ lambda expression and I would understand what is better in the following situation.

Suppose I want to write a very simple function to make a `sum`.

I can write it in the *"classic way"*:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a+b;
}

// and than call it in some way

int s = sum(1,2);
```

or in the *"modern way"*:

```
auto sum = [] (int a, int b) -> int {
  return a+b;
}

// and call it just after its declaration

int s = sum(1,2);
```

What is better in terms of performance, readabilty, portability for you?

In particular, I have analyzed source codes of other programmers who do for example:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
  auto sum = [] (int a, int b) -> int {
    return a+b;
  }
  return sum(a,b);
}

// ...
std::cout << foo(1,2) << std::endl;
// ...
```

Why should they (and I) prefer the *"modern way"*? Is not better to sum directly the numbers? What advantages should I expect from this approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `foo` example is completely ridiculous (IMO), are you sure it was exactly like that?

Comment: Why are you assuming that lambda expressions have any advantages?

Comment: Lambda functions are meant to be used in higher-order functions that take functions as arguments, so you don't pollute your namespace with single-use functions. Using them to replace function definitions is stupid, not modern.

Comment: The "best practice" for lambdas, if there is such a thing, is to use them when they are demonstrably better by your chosen measure (readability, complexity, performance, maintainability, time needed to get them working correctly, or whatever) than alternatives.   If you can't justify a claim that your usage of lambdas is better in some way than alternatives, then you probably should not use lambdas.

Comment: The question is primarly opinion based. However from my experience lambdas are typically used in functions that accept some sort of callback. Like comparison when you sort. Otherwise normal functions are used. Also modern compilers are very good at optimization and there shouldn't be any performance difference. Lambdas are just a syntacic sugar after all, in the simpliest case (no closure) they are typically transformed into a standalone function. Also, in my opinion, lambdas are less readable and are heavily abused nowadays.

Comment: Its not the "modern way" is about functional programming approach verses the imperative, functional programming becoming more popular nowadays since its safer in concurrent programming because of its immutable nature, today there are more cores for the modern CPU, making concurrent programming more appealing.

Comment: @Mat I know, this is why I asked! I found situations like this!

Comment: @user7860670 while studying I found the situations that I reported in the question, and because they look very strange to me, I thought to some advantage... maybe wrongly. This is what I would understand from more experienced programmers.